# Sympy Matrix M (modulo n)... How?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, modulus

```
import sympy
```

I am trying to find a matrix after taking each of its values (mod n).
I know numpy arrays work fine with this but i have to use sympy unfortunately.
Does anyone know of an inbuilt sympy function that does this or any other way round it? Thank you!

```
B = sympy.Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
print(B % 3)
```

This is my error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'MutableDenseMatrix' and 'int'
```

with numpy this is the correct output:

```
B = np.array([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
print(B % 3)

>>> [[2 0]
    [1 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use applyfunc to apply a function to every element:
`B.applyfunc(lambda x : x % 3)`

Answer (score 0):

With current SymPy this works:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> B = sympy.Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
>>> print(B % 3)
Matrix([[2, 0], [1, 2]])
```